# Texture coordinates on devices that don't support highp in fragment shaders

Tags: opengl-es, textures, webgl

My project is a 2D visualization of floating point data. The data is loaded into a floating point texture and then processed in fragment shaders. But many mobile devices don't support floating point textures in WebGL, so I'm emulating them with regular unsigned byte RBGA textures. This works well, but I'm running into issues on a device that doesn't support highp precision in fragment shaders. I have to manually perform the linear filtering as the floats need to be unpacked before filtering to get the correct result.

WebGL doesn't require devices to support high precision floats in fragment shaders. Most devices I experimented with so far still supported them, but now I found at least one that doesn't.

The device reports that it supports high precision (min and max = 2<sup>127</sup>, precision = 23) in vertex shaders at all precisions, but only mediump (min and max = 2<sup>15</sup>, precision = 10) in fragment shaders.

One value where I need high precision are texture coordinates. On this device I'm getting artifacts that look like ones I've previously encountered when the texture coordinate precision was too low.

I'm calculating the texture coordinates in the vertex shader and pass them on. In the vertex shader they're high precision, but what happens to them once they're in the fragment shader if the device doesn't support high precision in fragment shaders?

Are they automatically converted to medium precision?

Does that mean that it is impossible to access textures with higher precision coordinates than the maximum for the fragment shader even if the vertex shaders support higher precision?

Comment: Yes? What are you specifically trying to do? Put up some code so people can look for solutions

Comment: @gman my question is not really about the specific code, I just want to understand if accessing the texture is really limited by the precision of the fragment shader even if the coordinates are calculated in the vertex shader with higher precision.

Comment: Yes, they are limited in the fragment shader. How to work around that depends on what you're trying to do specifically. [This example needs highp to function correctly](http://twgljs.org/examples/tunnel.html). Compare iOS vs Desktop. After 20 seconds on iOS (as of iPhone6) it will start to diverge from the Desktop one because precision issues.